# Node.js + Express + i18next how to load language from database

Tags: node.js, database, express, configuration, i18next

my scenario is a Node.js + Express + Handlebars + i18next app.

I would like to set up default language upon a database configuration key.
If I decide that the default language should be X instead of Y, I would simply change it and save that choice in the backend of my app.
The problem is that I don't want to reload the entire app every time I change the default language and so I cannot do that in `i18next.init()` method.
The default language should be read from the database at every page request and used if not other choices have been done from the current user.
My idea was the following but it does not work:

```
const express = require('express');
const i18next = require('i18next');

const app = express();
...
i18next.init(...);
...
app.use((req, res, next) => {
        const lng = someLogicToDecideLanguage();
        i18next.changeLanguage(lng, (err, t) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            }
            console.log(i18next.language); // it's changed!
            next();
        });
    });
```

If I log `i18next.language` in the `changeLanguage` callback result, it seems changed but when the view is rendered the language does not change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I wasn't changing language on the correct translator instance, the one that i18next clones, makes available in the request and uses for translations. You must change `i18next.changeLanguage` to `req.i18n.changeLanguage`:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
        const lng = someLogicToDecideLanguage();
        req.i18n.changeLanguage(lng, (err, t) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            }
            console.log(i18next.language); // it's changed!
            next();
        });
    });
```